# What is the difference between "der Bedarf" and "die Anforderung"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I cannot find the difference between these two words.  I would like to know if there is a difference in when I should use one and not the other.  Thanks!

Comment: Whatr did you find out and what are examples of uncertainty?

Comment: Hi, Guidot, when I look up the definition for both, they all appear to be exactly the same.  But Cryck's reply has helped.

Comment: @Edicta: Then please report the definitions you found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Der Bedarf"* expresses a **need** of something.

> *Wir haben einen Bedarf von 10 Tonnen Stahl am Tag.*
>   *We have a need of 10 tons of steel per day.*

*"Die Anforderung"* expresses a **requirement** of something.

> *Unsere Anforderungen an die neue Mitarbeiterin sind...*
>   *Our requirements for the new employee are...*